# agree that, against that S V

Tags: grammar

> 1. I agree that he is guilty.
> 2. I am against that he is guilty.

Agree is usually used as an intransitive verb. And the meaning in the first sentence is close to an intransitive verb. So I think the original form of the sentence was "I agree on it that he is guilty".

In the same way, I think the second sentence's original form was "I am against it that he is guilty" because against is a preposition.

Another example :
He insist (on it) that she go to hospital

Is my thought right?  And if this is right, are these kind of phenomena - (it)+ that phrase - common in English ?  Or just applied to a few cases ?

Comment: #1's "original form" would be more like "I agree with the opinion that he is guilty." Similarly, #2's "original form" would be "I am against the opinion that he is guilty." Substituting "it" in either of these cases is not quite correct.  Actually, "I am against that he is guilty" itself also sounds wrong. I think most people would say either "I disagree that he is guilty" or "I am against finding him guilty." But really, all of these cases are called verb complements, where you use a verb + that phrase including another verb. And yes, they're common: "I think that," "I recommend that," etc.

Comment: Quick add: Your #2 is NOT a verb complement situation. In that case, because "against" is a preposition, it should be followed by either a noun  (i.e. "the opinion") or a verb phrase, in the form of a gerund, operating as a prepositional complement (i.e. "finding him guilty"). This is why "I am against that he is guilty" is wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I think so. The second sentence seems wrong.  Because we don't use "that phrase" right after a preposition. I understand : )  thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your thought is headed in the right direction.  Proposing a basic form "I agree to it that he is guilty" is very similar to an analysis proposed in the early days of transformational grammar.  A more recent analysis would be to start with *"I agree to that he is guilty" (which is ungrammatical as a surface form).  Prepositions in English do not tolerate objects which are that-clauses, so either with some suitable antecedent, the "that he is guilty" is pronominalized to "it", or else the preposition "to" is deleted.

Similarly, *"He insisted on that I go to the hospital" could turn up as "He insisted on it" or "He insisted that I go to the hospital".

Such constructions are discussed in McCawley's **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.